# Regex to match uncommented lines from a config file and only capture IP addresses from the string

Tags: regex, perl

Here is the contents of the file I'm trying to parse out.

```
# nameserver 3.3.3.3
nameserver 1.1.1.1
nameserver 2.2.2.2
```

So far I have the following :

```
^[^#].*\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b
```

Which works to ignore the commented lines but it matches nameserver 1.1.1.1 and nameserver 2.2.2.2

Ideally I'd like to match only lines that are not commented out and only match the IP addresses as the nameserver part of the string is unimportant to me.

I have found some regex here on StackOverflow that will accomplish one or the other but not both.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong would be awesome.

Thanks Everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Use a capturing group `( ... )` to capture the entire IP:

```
^[^#].*?\b((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\b
```

[See here](http://www.rubular.com/r/Aob4Kt8Zpr)

Comment: @Drew you will find your IP then in the variable `$1`

Comment: Thank you that's perfect. I knew it was something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at the [Regexp::Common::net](https://metacpan.org/module/Regexp%3a%3aCommon%3a%3anet) which does that already for you.